# PHP extension create array with hashtable

Tags: php, php-extension

How can I create multidimensional array with `hashTable API` in `PHP` extension [hashTable API link](http://www.phpinternalsbook.com/hashtables/hashtable_api.html) ? For the moment I create multidimensional array with this following lines :

```
zval *subarr;
array_init(return_value);

MAKE_STD_ZVAL(subarr);
array_init(subarr);

add_next_index_string(subarr, "hello", 1);

add_next_index_string(return_value, "test array", 1);
add_assoc_zval(return_value, "my-subarr", subarr);

return;
```

This code works fine, my return `array` is good. But I would like to know how to create this multidimensional array with `hashTable API` because this api allows more manipulation in particular to verify if a key exists (`zend_hash_index_exists`)